# Toad INCLUDE function

Tags: include, toad

I am trying to create a .sql file that calls other .sql files with toad. I came across the INCLUDE function for toad that seems like it's what I'm looking for but for reason I'm getting an error:

'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.' for some reason.

Any thoughts?

-- TOAD: INCLUDE '\RCHF3025.na.test.testtest.com\testtesttest\Recovery\RECOVERY_ANALYSIS_part1.sql';

Answer (score 0):

Is this Toad for Oracle? If so you want to use the @ notation.

@C:\Scripts\MyScript.sql

Comment: Using your filename which is on a network share then do the following... @\\RCHF3025.na.test.testtest.com\testtesttest\Recovery\RECOVERY_ANALYSIS_part1.sql